# GCP CLI Command to remove Data Catalog Tag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, command-line-interface, google-cloud-shell, google-data-catalog

what is the GCP CLI Command to remove (detach) a Data Catalog Tag from a BigQuery Dataset, and also CLI Command to Update Tag.

I am able to do it manually how to do it using Cloud Shell CLI gcloud command?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gcloud data-catalog tags update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/data-catalog/tags/update) and [gcloud data-catalog tags delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/data-catalog/tags/delete) commands.

The tricky part here is obtaining values for `--entry-group` and `--entry` parameters - BigQuery entries are automatically ingested to Data Catalog, and have automatically assigned entry group id and entry id. To get these values use [gcloud data-catalog entries lookup](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/data-catalog/entries/lookup) command.